# Does anyone know how to prove ~ ∀x (Ax→Bx) from Ǝx(Ax & ~Bx)?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

1. Ǝx(Ax & ~Bx)                               Premise
2. SHOW: ~ ∀x (Ax→Bx)

I really appreciate anyone who could help

The instructions for the homework were to Prove that the obverse of a particular negative entails the particular negative itself. i.e. that ‘Some A are not B’ entails ‘Not all A are B’. Then use morgans law. The book I am using is Critical Thinking by Moor-and Parker 11th edition.

Comment: **P & ~Q** is equivalen to **~ (P→Q)**.

Comment: You may want to include what rules you are permitted to use and the text you are using. Welcome to Philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this is to add an assumption with the goal of eliminating the existential quantifier by giving the variable *x* in the premise a name, say *a*.

Then add a second assumption of *Aa→Ba* with the goal to arrive at a contradiction. You should be able to easily reach that contradiction with the previous assumption. That will allow you to discharge the second assumption by introducing a negation.

With that negative conditional, introduce an existential quantifier on the name *a* calling the variable *x*. Now that you no longer have the name *a*, you can complete the elimination of the existential quantifier from the premise and discharge the first assumption.

A change of quantifier is all that is needed at this point to complete the proof.

I was able to complete the proof in 11 lines using Klement's Fitch-style natural deduction proof checker using the following rules: conjunction elimination, conditional elimination, contradiction introduction, negation introduction, existential elimination and introduction and change of quantifiers.

What you are using may require using different rules. The *forallx* text linked below may also provide a supplemental reference to whatever text you are using.

---

The following rule is available as *Rule 12 Implication (IMPL)* in the Group II Rules in Moore and Parker's *Critical Thinking* 9th Edition:

> This rule allows us to change a conditional into a disjunction and vice versa.
>   (P → Q) ↔ (~P ∨ Q)

Using this we could also start with the premise, Make an assumption to attempt to eliminate the existential quantifier over the variable *x* to obtain *Aa & ~Ba* using the specific name *a*. Use DeMorgan to transform that into *~(~Aa v Ba)* Use rule 12 to transform that into *~(Aa → Ba)*. Introduce the existential quantifier to replace the name *a* with *x*. This will allow us to discharge the assumption and then with a change of quantifiers obtain the final result.

This may be another way to obtain the result.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: The instructions for the homework were to Prove that the obverse of a particular negative entails the particular negative itself. i.e. that ‘Some A are not B’ entails ‘Not all A are B’. Then use morgans law. The book I am using is Critical Thinking by Moor-and Parker 11th edition.

Comment: @rom I added an alternate approach using a rule I found in an older edition of the text you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this seems accurate to the homework.